# MS DTC stopped BizTalk's transaction causing stuck message in Receive Pipeline

Tags: sql-server, biztalk, msdtc, biztalk-2016

We had the error that the Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) has cancelled a transaction of BizTalk which causes some stuck messages in the Receive Port, it has never happened before for years but it just occurs recently in 1 minute which causes few stuck messages. Is there anyway to make the Receive Location retries on error? What caused the DTC issue? I notice all the instances of stuck messages having  in active running service instances, is it an issue? and how can I fix it?

[image: Running service instances]

Error from BizTalk:

> There was a failure executing the receive pipeline:
> "CargoWise.eHub.Gateway.Pipelines.Rcv_ResolveInboundGatewayMessage,
> CargoWise.eHub.Gateway.Pipelines, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=4f570df270576350" Source: "Unknown " Receive Port:
> "Gateway_SelectInboxMessageByStatus_CACustoms" URI:
> "mssql://ehubtransactions.db.wisegrid.net//eHubTransactions?InboundId=SelectInboxMessagesByStatus&Category=CACustoms"
> Reason: 0x8004d00e

Error from SQL Server:

> Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) has stopped this transaction
> Error: 8522, Severity: 18, State: 1

It is a WCF-SQL receive port which pulls a message from database and its pipeline will dissemble and add properties to the message. The pipeline components don't access to database. However, there is no error in the query as it will update the db status to 1:

> UPDATE top (1) Inbox WITH (ROWLOCK)
> SET Status = 1 WHERE PK = @PK
> AND Status = 0
>
> SELECT PK,MessageTrackingID,Content
> FROM InboxMessage WITH (ROWLOCK)
> WHERE PK = @PK and InsertUTC = @InsertUTC

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/118250/four-part-distributed-query-issue-from-2014-to-2008r2)? But without more details of your system and code, no one can do much to help you.

Comment: You need to determine where it is failing?  Is it in the DB you are polling with the Receive Location?  Is it in a custom pipeline component that is accessing a DB, or is it in the BizTalk Message Box DB when it is trying to commit the message there?

Comment: Thanks @SMor, I will give it a try and let you know. More information, it is a WCF-SQL receive port which pulls a message from database and its pipeline will dissemble and add properties to the message. The pipeline components don't access to database. However, there is no error in the query as it will update the db status to 1:
Sorry, I cannot use @ character so I use at_ instead. 
UPDATE top (1) Inbox WITH (ROWLOCK) 
SET Status = 1
WHERE PK = at_PK AND Status = 0

SELECT PK,MessageTrackingID,Content
FROM InboxMessage WITH (ROWLOCK)
where PK = at_PK and InsertUTC = at_InsertUTC

Comment: Are there any triggers looking at the table you are updating?  Are there any linked servers configured?   How are you passing a parameter to a BizTalk WCF-SQL Receive Location?